# If $p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n>1$, $p(\overline{z}) $ is complex differentiable at $z=0$ if and only if $a_1=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $p(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n>1$, $p(\overline{z}) $ is complex differentiable at $z=0$ if and only if $a_1=0$. This is how I tried it but I am not sure whether this is the best way to show it.

Suppose $a_1=0$. Let $z\neq0$

$$\frac{p(\overline z)-p(0)}{\overline{z}-0}=a_n\overline z^{n-1}+...+a_2\overline z\implies \lim_{z\rightarrow0}\frac{p(\overline z)-p(0)}{\overline{z}-0}=0$$ Here I am not sure whether the denominator of the limit should be $\overline z $ or $z$.

Showing the other implication is tough for me any help will be much appreciated. Thanks alot

Comment: I might use the Cauchy-Riemann equation characterization of complex differentiability, since in this case it amounts to evaluating real derivatives of polynomials.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $p(\bar{z})$ is complex differentiable at $z = 0$ if and only if $\partial_{\bar{z}}|_{z=0}\, p(\bar{z}) = 0$, i.e., $p'(0) = 0$, or $a_1 = 0$.

Comment: Why should $\partial_{\bar{z}}|_{z=0}\, p(\bar{z}) = 0$ ?

Comment: Also I have proved that p'(0)=0 in my question though I do not know whether what I have done is correct

Comment: @Heisenberg you want to have $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{p(\bar{z}) - p(0)}{z - 0} = 0$, not $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{p(\bar{z}) - p(0)}{\bar{z} - 0} = 0$.

Comment: To answer you first question, it follows from the Cauchy-Riemann theorem.